# Recommended AWG for my power cord

Tags: pc, monitors, power-supply

I am using [EVGA - SuperNOVA G2 850W 80+ Gold Certified Fully-Modular ATX Power Supply](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16817438018) for my [current build](https://pcpartpicker.com/list/tg48WX), and my load seems to be 470W. For my computer monitors, I am using [Lenovo LT2452P](https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/solutions/pd021682). So, I need one power cord for PC and one for the monitor.

Questions:

1. I am trying to determine between 18/16/14 AWG which power supplies do I need for my PC and my monitor.
2. I already have some power cords, but how could I determine what AWG do they have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your load is 470W, then even at 110V (worst-case scenario), you are using 4.3A.  According to [the AutoZone guide](http://repairguide.autozone.com/znetrgs/repair_guide_content/en_us/images/0900c152/80/1c/02/e5/medium/0900c152801c02e5.gif), even at the thinnest (18AWG) wire, you can run 13 Amps through it (which is >3 times what you are using), and having it heat only to 150°F.  Therefore, you can run the 18AWG wire without any problems.

In general, when asking this, you should include the length of the power cable, and the temperature you'll use it in -- as it makes a huge difference.  For example, I had a 24AWG cable that could handle ~150A at below freezing, which is ~35 times as much as your scenario -- precisely because it is only a couple inches long.  One time I used it at above a freezing temperature, and it melted the isolation off of it.

Comment: The length could be 6-10 feet. The use is at the ambient temperature (25-100 F). The ampere (A) is what the standard American house hold would allow.

Comment: OK, I updated my answer to match your scenario.